# PERL: Can't use string ("undef") as a HASH ref while "strict refs"

Tags: perl

I got this weird error that I don't understand. I am trying to fill a hash by an another hash if I find a word ($target) else, fill it by "undef".

```
# Parsing ...

    my $target;
    my $idx;
    my $gene_description_ref  = \@gene_description;

    # ... the functional annotation 

    $target = $tax_function . "_topblasthit";
    $idx = undef;

    # Get the index of "arth_topblasthit" in the array @gene_description

    foreach ( 0 .. $#gene_description ) {
        if ( index ( $gene_description_ref->[ $_ ], $target ) >= 0 ) {
            $idx = $_;
            last;
        }
    }

    if (defined $idx){

        my @result = func_formatting($gene_description[$idx]);
        $gene_hash{$gene_id}{Function} = $result[0];
        $gene_hash{$gene_id}{Accession} = $result[1];

    } else {    # Gene has no function 
        $gene_hash{$gene_id} = "undef";
    }
```

But I got this error:

> Can't use string ("undef") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at insert_genes_maker.pl line 283,  line 7731.

any help please ?

Comment: A couple things. `"undef"` is a very misleading string, since it is defined and true. You need to use the bareword `undef` function to get an undefined value. An undefined value can then be used as a hashref, as you are apparently doing, and a hashref will magically appear due to [autovivification](https://perldoc.pl/perlglossary#autovivification). You could also instead assign an empty hashref `{}` explicitly, instead of undef. It's hard to say what is the correct thing to do without more context.

Comment: Btw, [List::MoreUtils::first_idx](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#firstidx-BLOCK-LIST) provides what your 6-line-`foreach`+comment does, with a fairly descriptive name I think (it also has the `first_index` alias)

Comment: @zdim the error mentioned would not occur at that assignment, but would occur when that string is attempted to be used like a hashref somewhere else.

Comment: @Grinnz Ah, of course -- got mislead into thinking about how one could restrict a (part of a) hash or some such ... deleting that comment then, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess: further down in your program you have at line 283 something like this:

```
my $function = $gene_hash{$some_var}->{Function};
```

This will fail with the mentioned error message, because you have scalars (i.e. "undef") stored as values in your hash. You either need to protect access e.g.

```
if (ref($gene_hash{$some_var}) eq "HASH") {
    # access value as hash here
    ...
```

or use some other method to detect "unknown", e.g.

```
} else {    # Gene has no function 
    $gene_hash{$gene_id} = {};
}
...
if (exists $gene_hash{$some_var}->{Function}) {
    # access function key in here
    ...
```

Comment: `if (ref($gene_hash{$some_var}) eq "HASH")` will warn. `if ($gene_hash{$some_var})` will do the trick if it's either a reference or undef.

Comment: Thanks, it help me

Comment: @ikegami it won't warn; ref always returns a defined value.